# make install fails when trying to install Python Audio Tools

Tags: python, audio, makefile, installation

I am trying to install Python Audio Tools, but when I run `make install` I get the following output:

```
python setup.py build
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'audiotools.cdio' extension
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/cdiomodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/cdiomodule.o
In file included from /usr/local/include/cdio/cdio.h:42:0,
                 from /usr/include/cdio/cdda.h:31,
                 from src/cdiomodule.h:2,
                 from src/cdiomodule.c:1:
/usr/local/include/cdio/types.h:108:7: error: expected ‘;’, identifier or ‘(’ before ‘_Bool’
In file included from src/cdiomodule.h:2:0,
                 from src/cdiomodule.c:1:
/usr/include/cdio/cdda.h:82:3: error: unknown type name ‘CdIo_t’
/usr/include/cdio/cdda.h:209:41: error: unknown type name ‘CdIo_t’
In file included from src/cdiomodule.c:1:0:
src/cdiomodule.h:98:5: error: unknown type name ‘CdIo_t’
In file included from src/cdiomodule.c:3:0:
/usr/include/cdio/audio.h:72:3: error: unknown type name ‘driver_return_code_t’
/usr/include/cdio/audio.h:72:47: error: unknown type name ‘CdIo_t’
/usr/include/cdio/audio.h:85:3: error: unknown type name ‘driver_return_code_t’
/usr/include/cdio/audio.h:85:42: error: unknown type name ‘CdIo_t’
/usr/include/cdio/audio.h:94:3: error: unknown type name ‘driver_return_code_t’
/usr/include/cdio/audio.h:94:45: error: unknown type name ‘CdIo_t’
/usr/include/cdio/audio.h:104:3: error: unknown type name ‘driver_return_code_t’
/usr/include/cdio/audio.h:105:5: error: unknown type name ‘CdIo_t’
/usr/include/cdio/audio.h:113:3: error: unknown type name ‘driver_return_code_t’
/usr/include/cdio/audio.h:113:52: error: unknown type name ‘CdIo_t’
/usr/include/cdio/audio.h:122:3: error: unknown type name ‘driver_return_code_t’
/usr/include/cdio/audio.h:122:43: error: unknown type name ‘CdIo_t’
/usr/include/cdio/audio.h:131:3: error: unknown type name ‘driver_return_code_t’
/usr/include/cdio/audio.h:131:47: error: unknown type name ‘CdIo_t’
/usr/include/cdio/audio.h:140:3: error: unknown type name ‘driver_return_code_t’
/usr/include/cdio/audio.h:140:41: error: unknown type name ‘CdIo_t’
In file included from src/cdiomodule.c:4:0:
/usr/include/cdio/track.h:34:5: error: redeclaration of enumerator ‘TRACK_FORMAT_AUDIO’
In file included from /usr/include/cdio/cdda.h:31:0,
                 from src/cdiomodule.h:2,
                 from src/cdiomodule.c:1:
/usr/local/include/cdio/cdio.h:93:5: note: previous definition of ‘TRACK_FORMAT_AUDIO’ was here
In file included from src/cdiomodule.c:4:0:
/usr/include/cdio/track.h:35:5: error: redeclaration of enumerator ‘TRACK_FORMAT_CDI’
In file included from /usr/include/cdio/cdda.h:31:0,
                 from src/cdiomodule.h:2,
                 from src/cdiomodule.c:1:
/usr/local/include/cdio/cdio.h:94:5: note: previous definition of ‘TRACK_FORMAT_CDI’ was here
In file included from src/cdiomodule.c:4:0:
/usr/include/cdio/track.h:36:5: error: redeclaration of enumerator ‘TRACK_FORMAT_XA’
In file included from /usr/include/cdio/cdda.h:31:0,
                 from src/cdiomodule.h:2,
                 from src/cdiomodule.c:1:
/usr/local/include/cdio/cdio.h:95:5: note: previous definition of ‘TRACK_FORMAT_XA’ was here
In file included from src/cdiomodule.c:4:0:
/usr/include/cdio/track.h:37:5: error: redeclaration of enumerator ‘TRACK_FORMAT_DATA’
In file included from /usr/include/cdio/cdda.h:31:0,
                 from src/cdiomodule.h:2,
                 from src/cdiomodule.c:1:
/usr/local/include/cdio/cdio.h:96:5: note: previous definition of ‘TRACK_FORMAT_DATA’ was here
In file included from src/cdiomodule.c:4:0:
/usr/include/cdio/track.h:38:5: error: redeclaration of enumerator ‘TRACK_FORMAT_PSX’
In file included from /usr/include/cdio/cdda.h:31:0,
                 from src/cdiomodule.h:2,
                 from src/cdiomodule.c:1:
/usr/local/include/cdio/cdio.h:97:5: note: previous definition of ‘TRACK_FORMAT_PSX’ was here
In file included from src/cdiomodule.c:4:0:
/usr/include/cdio/track.h:41:5: error: redeclaration of enumerator ‘TRACK_FORMAT_ERROR’
In file included from /usr/include/cdio/cdda.h:31:0,
                 from src/cdiomodule.h:2,
                 from src/cdiomodule.c:1:
/usr/local/include/cdio/cdio.h:100:5: note: previous definition of ‘TRACK_FORMAT_ERROR’ was here
In file included from src/cdiomodule.c:4:0:
/usr/include/cdio/track.h:42:5: error: conflicting types for ‘track_format_t’
In file included from /usr/include/cdio/cdda.h:31:0,
                 from src/cdiomodule.h:2,
                 from src/cdiomodule.c:1:
/usr/local/include/cdio/cdio.h:101:5: note: previous declaration of ‘track_format_t’ was here
In file included from src/cdiomodule.c:4:0:
/usr/include/cdio/track.h:73:5: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
/usr/include/cdio/track.h:112:3: error: unknown type name ‘cdtext_t’
/usr/include/cdio/track.h:112:30: error: unknown type name ‘CdIo_t’
/usr/include/cdio/track.h:120:3: error: unknown type name ‘CdIo_t’
/usr/include/cdio/track.h:120:11: error: conflicting types for ‘cdio_get_first_track_num’
In file included from /usr/include/cdio/cdda.h:31:0,
                 from src/cdiomodule.h:2,
                 from src/cdiomodule.c:1:
/usr/local/include/cdio/cdio.h:185:11: note: previous declaration of ‘cdio_get_first_track_num’ was here
In file included from src/cdiomodule.c:4:0:
/usr/include/cdio/track.h:126:3: error: unknown type name ‘CdIo_t’
/usr/include/cdio/track.h:136:3: error: unknown type name ‘CdIo_t’
/usr/include/cdio/track.h:142:3: error: unknown type name ‘CdIo_t’
/usr/include/cdio/track.h:147:3: error: unknown type name ‘CdIo_t’
/usr/include/cdio/track.h:153:3: error: unknown type name ‘CdIo_t’
/usr/include/cdio/track.h:153:18: error: conflicting types for ‘cdio_get_track_format’
In file included from /usr/include/cdio/cdda.h:31:0,
                 from src/cdiomodule.h:2,
                 from src/cdiomodule.c:1:
/usr/local/include/cdio/cdio.h:195:18: note: previous declaration of ‘cdio_get_track_format’ was here
In file included from src/cdiomodule.c:4:0:
/usr/include/cdio/track.h:163:3: error: unknown type name ‘CdIo_t’
/usr/include/cdio/track.h:163:8: error: conflicting types for ‘cdio_get_track_green’
In file included from /usr/include/cdio/cdda.h:31:0,
                 from src/cdiomodule.h:2,
                 from src/cdiomodule.c:1:
/usr/local/include/cdio/cdio.h:205:8: note: previous declaration of ‘cdio_get_track_green’ was here
In file included from src/cdiomodule.c:4:0:
/usr/include/cdio/track.h:169:3: error: unknown type name ‘CdIo_t’
/usr/include/cdio/track.h:183:3: error: unknown type name ‘CdIo_t’
/usr/include/cdio/track.h:183:9: error: conflicting types for ‘cdio_get_track_lba’
In file included from /usr/include/cdio/cdda.h:31:0,
                 from src/cdiomodule.h:2,
                 from src/cdiomodule.c:1:
/usr/local/include/cdio/cdio.h:214:9: note: previous declaration of ‘cdio_get_track_lba’ was here
In file included from src/cdiomodule.c:4:0:
/usr/include/cdio/track.h:197:3: error: unknown type name ‘CdIo_t’
/usr/include/cdio/track.h:197:9: error: conflicting types for ‘cdio_get_track_lsn’
In file included from /usr/include/cdio/cdda.h:31:0,
                 from src/cdiomodule.h:2,
                 from src/cdiomodule.c:1:
/usr/local/include/cdio/cdio.h:223:9: note: previous declaration of ‘cdio_get_track_lsn’ was here
In file included from src/cdiomodule.c:4:0:
/usr/include/cdio/track.h:208:3: error: unknown type name ‘CdIo_t’
/usr/include/cdio/track.h:219:3: error: unknown type name ‘CdIo_t’
/usr/include/cdio/track.h:233:3: error: unknown type name ‘CdIo_t’
/usr/include/cdio/track.h:245:3: error: unknown type name ‘CdIo_t’
/usr/include/cdio/track.h:245:8: error: conflicting types for ‘cdio_get_track_msf’
In file included from /usr/include/cdio/cdda.h:31:0,
                 from src/cdiomodule.h:2,
                 from src/cdiomodule.c:1:
/usr/local/include/cdio/cdio.h:232:8: note: previous declaration of ‘cdio_get_track_msf’ was here
In file included from src/cdiomodule.c:4:0:
/usr/include/cdio/track.h:251:3: error: unknown type name ‘CdIo_t’
/usr/include/cdio/track.h:262:3: error: unknown type name ‘CdIo_t’
/usr/include/cdio/track.h:262:16: error: conflicting types for ‘cdio_get_track_sec_count’
In file included from /usr/include/cdio/cdda.h:31:0,
                 from src/cdiomodule.h:2,
                 from src/cdiomodule.c:1:
/usr/local/include/cdio/cdio.h:241:16: note: previous declaration of ‘cdio_get_track_sec_count’ was here
src/cdiomodule.c: In function ‘CDImage_init’:
src/cdiomodule.c:340:21: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
src/cdiomodule.c:343:21: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
src/cdiomodule.c:346:9: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘cdio_open_cdrdao’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
src/cdiomodule.c:346:21: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
src/cdiomodule.c:349:21: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
src/cdiomodule.c: In function ‘CDImage_dealloc’:
src/cdiomodule.c:367:9: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘cdio_destroy’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
In file included from /usr/include/cdio/cdda.h:31:0,
                 from src/cdiomodule.h:2,
                 from src/cdiomodule.c:1:
/usr/local/include/cdio/cdio.h:116:8: note: expected ‘struct CdIo *’ but argument is of type ‘int *’
src/cdiomodule.c: In function ‘CDImage_read_sector’:
src/cdiomodule.c:398:36: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘cdio_read_audio_sector’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
In file included from /usr/include/cdio/cdda.h:31:0,
                 from src/cdiomodule.h:2,
                 from src/cdiomodule.c:1:
/usr/local/include/cdio/cdio.h:261:7: note: expected ‘const struct CdIo *’ but argument is of type ‘int *’
src/cdiomodule.c:399:10: error: ‘DRIVER_OP_SUCCESS’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/cdiomodule.c:399:10: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
src/cdiomodule.c: In function ‘CDImage_read_sectors’:
src/cdiomodule.c:429:37: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘cdio_read_audio_sectors’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
In file included from /usr/include/cdio/cdda.h:31:0,
                 from src/cdiomodule.h:2,
                 from src/cdiomodule.c:1:
/usr/local/include/cdio/cdio.h:267:7: note: expected ‘const struct CdIo *’ but argument is of type ‘int *’
src/cdiomodule.c:430:10: error: ‘DRIVER_OP_SUCCESS’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/cdiomodule.c: In function ‘cdio_identify_cdrom’:
src/cdiomodule.c:556:10: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘cdio_is_tocfile’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
src/cdiomodule.c:558:10: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘cdio_is_nrg’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Does anyone have any idea on how could I fix this issues?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which OS/arch are you using? Also which audio tools version?

Comment: Hi Salem! I am using Ubuntu 12.10 and the Audio Tools version is 2-17.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have some mixed up dependencies. Have you installed `libcdio` manually?

If so you can try to install those dependencies from the default repositories: on my system (12.04) with them Audio Tools compiles without any error:

```
sudo apt-get install libcdio-dev libcdio-paranoia-dev
```

Also as it seems it compiles some python modules, so you may need:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

If after this you still get that error, you probably will have to uninstall the `libcdio` library you installed manually.

Comment: Hi Salem! In the end I managed to solve the problem. During the first time I installed it as you suggested, but afterwards I tried installing it from source and now it works perfectly!

Comment: @zalman create an answer with the steps you followed and mark it as solved.